# Does the value set size of Redis key affect performance?

Tags: performance, redis, set

When performing `SISMEMBER` operation on a Redis key that has a set data structure value, does the set size of the key affect performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see in the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/sismember/), this method is O(1) in time complexity. It is not affected by set size.